# iTextSharp PDF only Rotates Once?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have found code online to rotate a PDF, I then use the move command to overwrite the original file. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this too. See code below:

```
string source = textBox1.Text;
     string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(source, null);
     string destination = filename + "-rot.pdf";
   
    Debug.WriteLine (destination);
                           
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
    int pagesCount = reader.NumberOfPages;

    for (int n = 1; n <= pagesCount; n++)
    {
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(n);
        PdfNumber rotate = page.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
        //int rotation = rotate == null ? 90 : (rotate.intValue() + 90) % 360;

        page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(-90));

    }
    
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
    File.Move(destination, source, true); //overwrite original with rotated and remove rotated file
```

However, I'm not sure I'm understanding the itextsharp pdf rotate function. If I then run the same thing again on the same pdf, it does not rotate it again. For example, if I had it set at 90, if I ran it twice I would expect the pdf to be at 180degrees to the original, but it does not work like that.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: *"However, I'm not sure I'm understanding the itextsharp pdf rotate function."* - Which "rotate function" do you mean? All you do is set the **Rotate** attribute value of each page to `-90`. The second time you do so obviously does not change anything, you set attributes to `-90` which were `-90` to start with. The commented line in your code shows what to do.

Comment: oh i see... i get it now. so it's setting a rotate attribute to the file. I thought it was kind of like when you print a pdf so it would continue rotating. interesting, didn't know pdf files had this sort of attribute.

Comment: :) ISO 32000-1, Table 30 – Entries in a page object: **Rotate**
integer
*(Optional; inheritable)* The number of degrees by which the page shall be rotated clockwise when displayed or printed. The value shall be a multiple of 90. Default value: 0.

Comment: haha, i see. Wow, everything is better to an ISO standard :D.
Out of interest, if a PDF is a vector doc, can it be converted to a DXF file, i'm guessing everything should stay to scale?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with DXF files, so I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing it’s rotating to 90 degrees and not by 90 degrees. So doing it twice (without saving and reloading perhaps) will just tell it to rotate to 90 not by 90.

Comment: but the code is saving the file, so i thought it would rotate it again
The only thing i can think of is that somewhere in the PDF it specifies the original angle of the document? so rotating to 90deg will always be the same, but i'm not sure

Comment: But in the snippet it appears you’re only rotating each page and then saving. Not attempting to rotate more than once. And you’d likely have to save it and then re-read the file to update the data else the original reference would likely have the original orientation.